# How to set a fixed length to be loaded in a table column via sql loader

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, aix, sql-loader

So I want to load a phone number via sql loader using my shell script cause when i try to load a data file that contains 9 digits, the script also loads the 9 digit rows. I only want the 10 digit rows to be loaded. The problem is i want the to set the sql loader to only accept rows that are exactly 10 digits.

Comment: please edit the question and show sample data and control file definition you have so far

Comment: Before running the loader, use bash/awk/perl/python/php/whatnot to filter the lines you wish to process.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you can't; SQL*Loader isn't capable of doing that. `WHEN` clause would be really nice, only if it accepted functions like `length`. But, it does not.

---

The simplest option I can think of is to load them all, and then delete rows you don't want. For example:

Table description:

```
SQL> desc test
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------
 TEL                                                VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> select * From test;

no rows selected
```

Control file:

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
( 
tel char(10)
)

begindata
1234567890
986532554
3216549878
21212
```

Run it:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test19.ctl log=test19.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Svi 4 21:46:17 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 4

SQL> select * From test;

TEL
----------
1234567890
986532554
3216549878
21212
```

Delete what you don't want:

```
SQL> delete from test where length(tel) < 10;

2 rows deleted.

SQL> select * From test;

TEL
----------
1234567890
3216549878

SQL>
```

---

Another option which would *silently* skip unwanted values is a database trigger. In order to do that, create a view based on the table and an instead-of trigger:

```
SQL> truncate table test;

Table truncated.

SQL> create or replace view v_test as select * From test;

View created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bivt
  2    instead of insert on v_test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if length(:new.tel) < 10 then
  6       null;
  7    else
  8       insert into test (tel) values (:new.tel);
  9    end if;
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test19.ctl log=test19.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Svi 4 21:52:59 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 4

SQL> select * From test;

TEL
----------
1234567890
3216549878

SQL>
```

This option is nice, but performance will suffer when you load a lot of data.

---

Yet another option is an external table. Its benefit is that source file can be treated as an ordinary Oracle table - you can write queries directly against it. In order to use it, create a directory and grant privileges to user which will use it:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create directory ext_dir as 'c:\temp';

Directory created.

SQL> grant read, write on directory ext_dir to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Create external table:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table test_ext
  2    (tel varchar2(10))
  3  organization external
  4    (type oracle_loader
  5     default directory ext_dir
  6     access parameters (records delimited by newline
  7                        fields terminated by ','
  8                          (tel char(10))
  9                       )
 10     location ('test.txt')
 11    )
 12    reject limit unlimited;

Table created.

SQL>
```

Test.txt contents:

```
1234567890
986532554
3216549878
21212
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> select * From test_ext;

TEL
----------
1234567890
986532554
3216549878
21212

SQL>
```

Now, insert only rows you want to accept:

```
SQL> truncate table test;

Table truncated.

SQL> insert into test (tel)
  2  select tel
  3    from test_ext
  4    where length(tel) = 10;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from test;

TEL
----------
1234567890
3216549878

SQL>
```

The only drawback of this option is that you have to have access to directory which is (generally speaking) located on the database server, so you'll have to talk to your DBA.

---

As you can see, quite a few options, but none exactly like you'd want.